# Custom keyboard • telegram bot in Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, telegram, telegram-bot

Hello i have some issues with my telegram bot, developed in ruby with '[telegrammer](https://github.com/mayoral/telegrammer)' client.

1)

```
  when '/lottery'
    question = 'choose a number:'
    answers =
      Telegram::Bot::Types::ReplyKeyboardMarkup.new(
      keyboard: [
        ["1", "2", "3"],
        ["4", "5", "6"],
        ["7", "8", "9"],
        [" ", "0", " "]
      ],

      one_time_keyboard: true
      )

    bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: question, reply_markup: answers)
```

How can i interact with the answer of the user? Like

```
if answers == "1"
    bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "You have selected 1", reply_markup: answers)
end
```

2) How can i read a command like

> /*** @user1

and then the bot will says

> @user1 the @user tell you ***

Thank you so much in advance...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I don't remember, but I think not, I stopped working on telegrams bot, sorry

Comment: Alright! No problemo! For the time being I could do a work around by predefining the commands in the inline keyboard, that lets user automatically select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
When a user clicks something on the keyboard, there is no special command sent. It doesn't matter if if a user clicks "1" on the keyboard are just sends a message with "1" to your bot (assuming the bot receives that message). So you will just receive the standard data like

```
"message" : {
    "text" : "1"
    #...
}
```

So you will probably have a code that looks about this

```
#If message text equals '1'
when '1'
    #Do something
```

2.

I don't know how the 'telegrammer' client works, but it's probably the
    best if your first check if the message text matches a certain
    regex. If the text does match, then you only need to split the
    message text to get the parts you want so you can build your reply.

Comment: However, `When '1' `acts like a command and not like user input for a particular command!

I am thinking should I use `def ()` and call this `def` when the user types that specific command?